# Xperia Z3 boot loop after TWRP installation

Tags: boot-loop, twrp, sony-xperia-z3

My Xperia Z3 was running Android 5.0.2. The model is D6653. I didn't check the firmware build number.

I followed [these steps](http://www.android.gs/install-twrp-recovery-on-sony-xperia-z3/).

Everything was successful with no errors.

```
➜  Sdk  sudo $(which fastboot) devices             
[sudo] password for eric: 
➜  Sdk  sudo $(which fastboot) devices
CB5A276UDL  fastboot
➜  Sdk  sudo $(which fastboot) flash boot ~/Downloads/bootZ3monxtest01\ \(1\).img
sending 'boot' (13056 KB)...
OKAY [  0.413s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.875s]
finished. total time: 1.288s
➜  Sdk  sudo $(which fastboot) reboot
rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.051s
```

Now my phone is just flashing TWRP logo repetitively - I cant' go into recovery.  <s>I can't even get into fastboot mode anymore so I can't execute any more commands from my computer.</s>

I'm using a Ubuntu laptop.

What should I do e.g. try to install another recovery [like this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3/orig-development/d66xx-cwm-based-recovery-6-0-4-7-root-t2890116)?

Comment: I'd say the person who wrote that howto messed up: recovery mustn't be flashed to the boot partition, but to the recovery partition. With your device no longer booting up (I doubt it would even boot to recovery), and not even fastboot working, you will have a hard time getting that fixed – I'm not aware of any solution here (unless there's a bootable SD card for that device which could be used to fix it up).

Comment: "why all the tutorials I found says `fastboot flash boot bootZ3monxtest01.img` instead?" I had one that had the boot image and recovery in the same .img file so it contained the kernel, ramdisk and the recovery image. Hence flashing the boot image file will be enough to get a custom recovery in that case.

Comment: The guide you linked tells you to type `fastboot flash boot bootZ3monxtest01.img`, which is *wrong*. I actually made the exact same mistake thanks to that stupid guide. It's supposed to be `fastboot flash recovery bootZ3monxtest01.img`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got into fastboot again, flashed another boot image containing CWM recovery (I don't think TWRP is to blamed but I just want a clean start).

The same issue happened as with TWRP boot image - I could not boot into system normally even after wiping data, cache partition and dalvik cache. I can only boot into recovery.

So I transfer [a pre-rooted rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3/general/d6603-5-0-2-flashable-stock-23-1-0-690-t3056361) through `adb push` while the phone is still in recovery mode. Then I performed **install zip** and I got my phone rooted with Android Lollipop 5.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you can enter into fastboot, you can execute the commands below
`fastboot flash recovery ~/Downloads/bootZ3monxtest01.img`
and `fastboot reboot` and install a custom rom.

`flash boot boot.img` is used to flash kernel images.
boot.img is a file which contains kernel and ramdisk.

More on Boot & Recovery images can be found [here](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Unpack%2C_Edit%2C_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images#Structure_of_boot_and_recovery_images)

Comment: why all the tutorials I found says `fastboot flash boot bootZ3monxtest01.img` instead? http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3/development/root-stock-kernel-twrp-v01-test-28-09-t2889794, http://www.theandroidsoul.com/install-twrp-recovery-sony-xperia-z3-65251/, http://www.infysim.org/2014/09/rooting-guide-sony-xperia-z3-rooting-and-installing-custom-recovery.html# etc.

Comment: @eric `flash boot boot.img` is for flashing kernel.. `flash recovery recoveey.img` is for flashing recovery

Comment: then all the tutorials listed are wrong?

Comment: I looked upon the [1st link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3/development/root-stock-kernel-twrp-v01-test-28-09-t2889794) It says that the file `bootZ3monxtest01.img` is **ADV STOCK KERNEL + TWRP v2.8.0.1** . The img is "Kernel+Recovery". The tutorials might not be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You flashed to the boot partition, while you should have flashed to recovery partition. To fix, grab the boot images, boot in to fastboot and flash the boot image to the boot partition. To install TWRP correctly switch "boot" out with "recovery" in the commands. Since you can't get to fastboot the only solution for you would be something like this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2646405

Comment: OP wrote "*I can't even get into fastboot mode anymore*".

Comment: Well. Then. I don't even know.

Comment: thanks guys I don't know why but I was able to get into fastboot again yesterday and solved my problem

Comment: Yeah the guide OP linked to is pretty much crap, I soft bricked my device in exactly the same way. I can still recover and all, but damn. Had to erase my user data in the process.